# bindingsource.AddNew method adds two record instead of 1

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework-4, bindingsource

this problem is in a windows form application with Entity framework.

source code (V.S 2010) :
https://rapidshare.com/files/1553732530/WindowsFormsApplication8.rar

I have an *"employes"* entity  that have ID,Name fields and self association with " zero or 1 **TO** many " multiplicity. and two navigation properties 1-Manager 2-personnel

Every manager can have zero or more personnel and every personnel can have zero or more manager.

in a form, i have two data grid view, one for managers and another for  personnel of current selected manager in first data grid view. until now every thing is ok, but when i call below code, the personnel BindingSource adds two record instead of one record

```
        employeBindingSource.AddNew();
        Employe p=(Employe)personnelBindingSource.AddNew();
        p.Manager = (Employe)employeBindingSource.Current;
```

What is the problem?

Comment: do you release your release entity context ? by the way, even you release it, so it will happen memory leak

Comment: my problem is, when i set manager of current record of employeBindingSource (p.Manager = (Employe)employeBindingSource.Current;)

Comment: personnelBindingSource have two new record instead of 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code works properly

```
        employeBindingSource.AddNew();
        Employe p = new Employe();

        p.Manager = (Employe)employeBindingSource.Current;
```